# Nginx redirect to domain name instead of IP address

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns

I have a domain name from godaddy consider it as a www.example.com, and server from linode (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I have a static web page which is served through nginx by listening port 9000, consider it as 0.0.0.0:9000.

```
server {
    root /home/webapps/mysite;
    index index.html index.htm;

    listen 0.0.0.0:9000;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

I added the domain name in the linode DNS manager and also added in the godaddy Domain Forward Setting.

In the browser if  I use 0.0.0.0:9000 my site page opens correctly and if I use with domain name **example.com** in the browser the domain name is changed to ip address and my page opens, why it is happening so, why my domain name is changing back to IP address, did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***"domain forward"*** feature of a domain registrar suggests that you've configured to have your domain name `redirect` ([`301 Moved Permanently`](http://ngx.su/src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c#NGX_HTTP_OFF_3XX)) to another site — you apparently must have configured it to redirect to [http://192.0.2.50/](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737), hence, that's what would show up in your browser.

---

The correct way to configure the domain (which would avoid the above issue you're having) is to ***instead change the DNS settings***:

- add a record named `@` (meaning, `example.com.`) with type `A` and value of `192.0.2.50`
- add a record named `www` (meaning, `www.example.com.`) of type `CNAME` and value `@`

The above settings you can either make within the interface of your registrar, or, alternatively, by ***delegating*** the domain name to your hosting provider, and subsequently maintaining the settings there.

Obviously, in order to not have to specify the port number, you'd have to change your nginx configuration to run it on port 80 for the domain to work properly.

---

*Alternatively*, if the above is too complex, another quick way to avoid the IP address from showing up in the browser is to use ***"domain masking"*** type of forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming the app is already running at localhost:9000, you can set up reverse proxy like this.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

For more information, please refer to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04